# Vertical carousel angular 2

Tags: angular, carousel

Is there some great plugin for angular 2 vertical carousel, where animations are included as well?

I Already tried to use ng-angular carousel, I made it vertically but the problem with this carousel starts when each slide has to have different height.

Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Goto this link](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper)

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
    direction: 'vertical',
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
```